# Why is AWS Elasticbeanstalk with Application Load Balancer not Balancing Traffic?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

For some reason my AWS elasticbeanstalk environment, which is using an Application Load Balancer is not balancing the traffic evenly.

All of the instances are the same instance size, but for some reason one instance's CPU is always pegged at 100%. If I delete the instance the other one will just become pegged and the newly created instance will just sit there with minimal load.

I would expect to see both of these at 100% or more evenly balanced at something like 50% and 50%.

[image]

Comment: Check your ` Stickiness policy enabled box to enable or disable sticky sessions.` you might have configured cookie duration  Cookie duration to configure a sticky session's duration

Comment: check this too https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-unequal-traffic-routing/ instance might not be distributed equally across availability zones